# full_join multiple dataframes without overwriting previous values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("State" = c("AK", "AK", "AZ", "AZ", "AR", "AR"),
                 "County" = c("Anchorage", "Juneau", "Pima", "Maricopa", "Arkansas", "Washington"),
                 "Population" = c(200, 30, 100, 3000, 20, 200))
```

I'm doing some calculations by reading in specific files for each `State` using a separate `for` loop. I'm not putting the loop here because I can't simplify it easily, but basically the `for` loop returns mini dataframes like below:

```
df_AK <- data.frame("State" = c("AK", "AK"), 
                    "County" = c("Anchorage", "Juneau"),
                    "new_column" = c(30, 10))
df_AZ <- data.frame("State" = c("AZ", "AZ"),
                    "County" = c("Pima", "Maricopa"),
                    "new_column" = c(100, 20))
df_AR <- data.frame("State" = c("AR", "AR"), 
                    "County" = c("Arkansas", "Washington"),
                    "new_column" = c(10, 50))
```

What I'm ultimately interested in is getting `df_final`, which should look like:

```
df_final <- data.frame("State" = c("AK", "AK", "AZ", "AZ", "AR", "AR"),
             "County" = c("Anchorage", "Juneau", "Pima", "Maricopa", "Arkansas", "Washington"),
             "Population" = c(200, 30, 100, 3000, 20, 200),
             "new_column" = c(30, 10, 100, 20, 10, 50))
```

I initially tried doing this by making an empty column in `df` and using `full_join` like below, but I realized that when I bind `df_AZ` to `df`, the `new_column` values from `df_AK` that I merged to `df` get overwritten as NAs. Is there a way to ignore the NAs and only merge numeric values on `full_join` so that I won't keep on overwriting the `new_column` values? Or is there another function I can use other than `full_join` to get `df_final`?

```
df$new_column <- NA
df_final <- full_join(df, df_AK)
df_final <- full_join(df, df_AZ) ...
```

Comment: Please try the data you give us; this has (at least) two quotes missing.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the quotes!

Comment: You don't want a join, you want to `dplyr::bind_rows()`, and the easiest way to do that is to ensure that all the individual data frames are in a single list. Doing that will require modifying code you haven't shared. One way would be to create an empty list `result <- vector(mode = "list",length = some_length)` of the appropriate length and then insert each data frame in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

We could do a `left_join` with combined df's achieved by `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, bind_rows(df_AK, df_AZ, df_AR), by = c("State", "County"))

  State     County Population new_column
1    AK  Anchorage        200         30
2    AK     Juneau         30         10
3    AZ       Pima        100        100
4    AZ   Maricopa       3000         20
5    AR   Arkansas         20         10
6    AR Washington        200         50
```